# Изменить значение свойства left

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Прошу помочь с информацией по несложному вопросу.
Есть разметка:

```
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item_2"></div>
    <div class="item_3"></div>
    <div class="item_4"></div>
```

Четыре элемента абсолютно спозиционированны,имеют след. значения:

- item   -> left 0;
- item_2 -> left: 25%;
- item_3 -> left: 50%;
- item_4 -> left: 75%;

Могу ли я добавить к мои элементам класс, что бы их значение поменялось на + 15%?

Например добавить класс "active", после которого у :

- item станет left 15%;
- item_2 станет left 40%;
- item_3 станет left 65%;
- item_4 станет left 90%;

Если возможно, подскажите что нужно добавить в этот самый класс active.

```
active {
    ????;
}
```

Comment: Можете конечно, в чем вопрос? Опишите конкретнее задачу.

Comment: Можете, только вот нужно учитывать, что это работает через `position`, иначе свойство `left, etc...` работать не будут

Comment: Конкретнее? Ну допустим "Подскажите что нужно записать в класс active, что бы решить эту задачу".
Что касается ответа :"Можете, только вот нужно учитывать, что это работает через position" - я в курсе, поэтому в начале и написал что "Четыре элемента абсолютно спозиционированны".
Если я не совсем понятно выразился, я имел ввиду что эти 4 дива лежать в конейнере у которого position: relative; а эти 4 дива имеют position: absolute; Вопрос был что мне написать в класс "active", что бы получить желаемый результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если менять именно значение `left` - то в лоб:

```
.item {left:0;}
.item_2 {left:25%;}
.item_3 {left:50%;}
.item_4 {left:75%;}

.active.item {left:15%;}
.active.item_2 {left:40%;}
.active.item_3 {left:65%;}
.active.item_4 {left:90%;}
```

Если же задача сдвинуть блоки и прописать стиль только для класса .active (чтобы не переписывать `left` у целой кучи элементов, если вдруг изначальные значения поменяются), то лучше навеситься на какое-то другое свойство, берущее величину в % из того же источника, что и `left`. Например, на `margin-left`:

```
.active {margin-left:15%;}
```